# Get firstresponder in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, macos, cocoa

I am having trouble trying to figure out which `UITextField` is the current First Responder.

What I am trying to do is a set a boolean value if the user clicks in a particular `UITextField`. So to do that I need to be able to tell if this particular text field has become the first responder.

I know how to set the first responder but just not sure how to tell if a field has actually become the first responder.

Answer (score 25):

> [...] but just not sure how to tell if a field has actually become the
>   first responder.

`UIView` inherits the `isFirstResponder` method from `UIResponder` which tells you this.

The easiest way to find whatever the first responder is without checking individual controls/views and without multiple methods for all of the different types of possible first responders is to just make a category on `UIView` which adds a `findFirstResponder` method:

**UIView+FirstResponder.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (FirstResponder)
- (UIView *)findFirstResponder;
@end
```

**UIView+FirstResponder.m**

```
#import "UIView+FirstResponder.h"

@implementation UIView (FirstResponder)

- (UIView *)findFirstResponder
{
    if ([self isFirstResponder])
        return self;

    for (UIView * subView in self.subviews) 
    {
        UIView * fr = [subView findFirstResponder];
        if (fr != nil)
            return fr;
    }

    return nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: Why does it return UIView and not UITextField?

Comment: @yourfriendzak Because UITextField is not the only type of object that can become the first responder.

Answer (score 4):

Why not using the UITextFieldDelegate and implement the textFieldDidBeginEditing: method? This will be called as soon as the textfield gains the focus.

[UITextFieldDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
if(![myTextField isFirstResponder])
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I might do like this

Add property to ViewController

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *firstRespondField;
```

Register TextField Notificaiton

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(textFieldTextDidBeginEditing:)
                                               name:UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification
                                             object:nil];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(textFieldTextDidEndEdition:)
                                               name:UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification
                                             object:nil];
```

Dont forget remove it on Dealloc

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Then Implement 2 method

```
    - (void)textFieldTextDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

  self.firstRespondField = aNotification.object;

}

- (void)textFieldTextDidEndEdition:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

  self.firstRespondField = nil;

}
```

Finally, I might get FirstResponder object by

```
self.firstRespondField
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call UIView.IsFirstResponder on the view you want to know if it's the first responder.