# iOS - how to dismiss keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikeyboard

In my app, I press a button and it pulls up a modal presentation sheet (for iPad). Within this modal view I have a scrollview within my main view, and 1 text field within my scroll view.

```
view controller
    view
        scrollview
            text field
```

Nothing I have tried resigns the keyboard and I don't know why. The only thing that happens is the blinking cursor in the textfield goes away. My class is the delegate for the scrollview and text fields. Here is what I have tried:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    [self.titleTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.titleTextField endEditing:YES];
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self.view resignFirstResponder];
    [self.scrollView endEditing:YES];
    [self.scrollView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

The method does get called, but the keyboard doesn't go away. Can anyone help me or at least tell me why?

Here is how I present this modalpresentation view:

(it comes from a tableviewcontroller)

didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
EditVideo *targetController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"editVideo"];

        targetController.delegate = self;

        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:targetController];

        navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

        [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];

        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

Comment: My guess is that your titleTextField is either not the first responder, or you are making it again somewhere else in your code. Take a look here too:http://stackoverflow.com/a/1823360/312312

Comment: Have you confirmed you are first responder ? Try Steves's gewtfirstresponder code for UIView:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772468/get-firstresponder-in-objective-c                                                        Also does scrollViewDidScroll get called after the scroll and you may have put focus back on the scrollview and re-initiated the first responder ?

Comment: When I try to find the firstResponder, it returns null.

Comment: However, when I check [self.titleTextField isFirstResponder], it returns 1(true).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the iPad for any any non-fullscreen presented ViewController, you must implement `-(BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal` to return `NO` to dismiss the keyboard.

```
- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal
{
    return NO;
}
```

Once that is implemented, you can call `[self.view endEditing:YES];`.

Edit:
The other common cause of this problem is returning `NO` from `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField`. Implement the method in the UITextFieldDelegate and have it return `YES` unconditionally to prove that it is not a factor.

Comment: Tried that, unfortunately still nothing :(

Comment: @JosueEspinosa: Did you implement it in both the presented (Form Sheet) view controller as well as the presenting?

Comment: I did. The only thing that changes is the text field loses its cursor, the keyboard remains where it's at.

Comment: I updated my answer to now include both causes to this problem that I've encountered. You probably have a bug in your code. Post your view controller code so we can look it over.

Comment: Updated my question. Btw the text field wasn't made programmatically, it was made through Interface Builder. I don't alter the text field in any way in any class.

Comment: To confirm, in your `EditVideo` view controller, you are implementing `-disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal`?

Comment: Yes, both in EditVideo and the view controller where it is presented. I honestly have no idea why it isn't working.

Comment: I found the culprit in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019709/modal-dialog-does-not-dismiss-keyboard/10507689#10507689). The `UINavigationController` does not implement `-disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal`. There are several possible solutions depending on your intent.

Comment: My intent is to dismiss the keyboard when the user scrolls in the scroll view.

Comment: That's not quite what I meant. The options you have are a) create your own subclass of `UINavigationController` so you can override the function or b) create a category on UINavigationController to override it in the standard class.

Comment: I created a category on UINavigationController with the code provided in the link, then imported into EditVideo.m, but it still doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I can't tell you if you're doing something wrong without looking over every detail of your project and storyboard. This is the right cause, but you have to figure out the rest.

Comment: It's not that important to my project, just drives me crazy. Thanks for your help Neal. I'll accept your answer and eventually figure it out :)

Comment: Depending on how important it is, you could create a GitHub project of the minimum code to create the problem and post it with your question. Then you would get a definitive solution.